# how can I provide multipe secrets in one yaml file?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

How can I define multiple secrets in one file?
Seems that providing multiple secrets doesn't work.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: ca-secret
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt: LS0tLDR
  tls.key: LS0tLDR
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: envoy-secret
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt: LS0tLS1
  tls.key: LS0tLS1
```

I am not able to use multiple files because I need to generate a single template using helm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have separate manifests in one yaml file by separating them with `---`. This will work:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: ca-secret
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt: LS0tLDR
  tls.key: LS0tLDR
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: envoy-secret
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt: LS0tLS1
  tls.key: LS0tLS1
```

Comment: Looks fine - thank you. BTW do you know how I can provide path to the cert file in helm?

Comment: how do you create the secret the the "kubectl create secret" command since it expects a name for the secret but there's multiple being created?

Comment: This does only work with a file, so `kubectl create -f <flile-with-multiple-secrets`, though I'd rather use kubectl apply.